# How to set the height for menuFlyoutSubItem generated menuFlyout in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

How to set the height for the MenuFlyoutSubItem's -> MenuFlyout height in uwp?

Sample Image is attached below,

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [`MenuFlyout` theme resources](https://%20https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/MenuFlyout_themeresources.xaml#L320), there is only the property `MinHeight` in `MenuFlyoutPresenter` to modify the height, but this will apply to all `MenuFlyoutSubItem`, and the height cannot be set individually for one SubItem.

```
private void MenuFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    MenuFlyout menuFlyout = sender as MenuFlyout;
    Style style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(MenuFlyoutPresenter) };
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(MinHeightProperty, "500"));
    menuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle = style;
}
```